# Tem algo de errado em algum codigo mas não consigo achar, estou fazendo um tela de login

Tags: php, html, mysql, login

> Eu estou fazendo um sistema login , o mesmo fica dando erro falando que a senha e o email estão errados, mesmo eu sabendo que a senha e o email esta certo, se puderem me ajudar agradeço

> **login.php**

```
<?php 
require_once 'classes/usuarios.php';
$u = new Usuario;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tela de login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="corpo-form">
    <h1>Entrar</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="on">
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" autocomplete="on">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Acessar">
        <a href="cadastro.php">Ainda não é inscrito? <strong>Cadastre-se</strong></a>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
    //verificar se não está vazio
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($senha))
    {
        $u->conectar("login", "localhost","root","");
        if($u->msgErro == "")
        {
            if($u->logar("$email, $senha"))
            {
                header("location:AreaPrivada.php");
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <div class="msg-erro">
                Email e/ou senha estão incorretos!
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
        }
    }
    else
    {
            ?>
            <div class="msg-erro">
            Preencha todos os campos!
            </div>
            <?php
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

> **cadastro.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'classes/usuarios.php';
    $u = new Usuario;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tela de login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="corpo-form-cad">
    <h1>Cadastro</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" maxlength="30">
        <input type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="30">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="40">
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" maxlength="15">
        <input type="password" name="confSenha" placeholder="Confirmar senha">
        <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar">
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
//verificar se o botão foi apertado
if(isset($_POST['nome']))

{
    $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
    $telefone = addslashes($_POST['telefone']);
    $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
    $confirmarSenha = addslashes($_POST['confSenha']);
    //verificar se não está vazio
    if(!empty($nome) && !empty($telefone) && !empty($email) && !empty($senha) && !empty($confirmarSenha))
    {
        $u->conectar("login", "localhost","root","");
        if($u->msgErro == "")//não teve nenhum erro
        {
            if ($senha == $confirmarSenha)
            {
                if($u->cadastrar($nome,$telefone,$email,$senha))
                {

                    ?>
                    <div id="msg-sucesso">
                        Cadastado com sucesso! 
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="msg-erro">
                        Email já cadastrado!
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                ?>
                <div class="msg-erro">
                    Senha e confirmar senha não correspondem!
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {

            echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
        }
    }
    else
    {
            ?>
            <div class="msg-erro">
                Preencha todos os campos!
            </div>
            <?php
    }
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

> **usuarios.php**

```
<?php 

class Usuario 
{
    private $pdo;
    public $msgErro = ""; // tudo ok

    public function conectar($nome = null, $host = null, $email = null, $senha = null)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        try 
        {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host,$email,$senha);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function cadastrar($nome = null, $telefone = null, $email = null, $senha = null)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        //verificar se já existe o email cadastrado
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuarios FROM usuarios WHERE email = :e");
        $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            return false; //já está cadastado
        }
        else
        {
        //caso não esteja
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, telefone, email, senha) VALUES (:n, :t, :e, :s)");
            $sql->bindValue(":n",$nome);
            $sql->bindValue(":t",$telefone);
            $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
            $sql->bindValue(":s",md5($senha));
            $sql->execute();
            return true;//cadastrado com sucesso

        }

    }

    public function logar($email = null, $senha = null)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        //verificar o email e a senha estão cadastrados, se sim
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuarios FROM usuarios WHERE email = :e AND senha = :s");
        $sql->bindValue(":e,",$email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s",md5($senha));
        $sql->execute(array(':e' => $email, ':s' => $senha));
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            //entrar no sistema (sessão)
            $dado = $sql->fetch();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id_usuarios'] = $dado['id_usuarios'];
            return true; //logado com sucesso

        }
        else
        {
            return false; //não foi possivel logar
        }
    }

}

?>
```

> **AreaPrivada**
>
> > Esse é o lugar onde ele deveria me enviar caso eu fosse logado com sucesso

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id_usuarios'])) 
    {
        header("location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

?>


Seja bem vindo
<a href="sair.php">Sair</a>
```

> **sair.php**
>
> > esse é apenas para caso uma pessoa que não tenha logado tente entrar na area privada, que eu testei e esta funcionando normalmente

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['id_usuarios']);
    header("location: login.php")

?>
```

> Os comandos do banco de dados são esses:
>
> > O **nome do banco de dados é login** e o **nome da tabela é usuarios**

```
create database login;

use login;

create table usuarios (
    id_usuarios int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    nome varchar(30),
    telefone varchar(30),
    email varchar(40)
    senha varchar(32)
);
```

> eu tambem vi o console, da pagina e só tem isso nela
> [image: imagem do console]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e trocar o código fornecido por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu código tem um problema bem simples, mas que as vezes passa despercebido. O problema encontra-se em: usuarios.php
Veja o SEU código abaixo:

```
<?php 
if ($u->logar("$email, $senha")) {
    header("location:AreaPrivada.php");
} else {
?>
    <div class="msg-erro">
        Email e/ou senha estão incorretos!
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Mais especificamente nesta linha:

```
$u->logar("$email, $senha")
```

O seu if, está procurando por strings. O correto deveria ser:

```
$u->logar($email, $senha)
```

Fazendo esta simples alteração, o seu código já passa a funcionar, como você pode ver nesta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]